# Zooming image to mouse cursor with Javascript and returning to the images original position

Tags: javascript

Part of my app requires the user to be able to use the mousewheel to zoom in on an image which is already centered inside a larger container element.

I am using jQueryUI to provide a slider with which the zoom is controlled manually.

When zooming withe mousewheel, the viewport adjusts so that the user is always zooming towards to mouse cursor providing exactly the same behaviour as google maps in terms of zoom functionality.

Also, in order to provide a better experience than using css transitions I have written a momentum based smooth scroll algorithm to make the zooming as smooth as possible.

Everything works perfectly with one exception.

To replicate the problem please follow these steps on the provided jsFiddle:

1. move mouse cursor to the center of the image.
2. Very gently move the mousewheel one notch so that the smoothwheel takes over an zooms you in a little.
3. Then move the mouse cursor to another point of the already slightly zoomed image
4. Zoom in again, as far as you want this time
5. Finally zoom all the way out

You will see that the zoomed out image is now misplaced (as the translates have not been removed).

The behaviour I want is for the zoomed out image to return to its original position once the scale is set back to `1`.

If you remove the css `translate` from the image in Firebug you will see that the image returns to the correct location.

Therefore this could easily be achieved with a simple conditional like so:

```
if(scale == 1){
    //remove transforms completely
}
```

However doing this would provide a jumpy experience and I would like the image to gradually zoom back out to the original position as the user zooms out.

It is worth mentioning that if you zoom all the way in without moving the mouse you will find that everything is correct when you zoom back out.  This is simple because no `translate` gets added to the elements transform, simply a `scale` and `transform-origin`.  In my code the `translate` only gets added when you change zoom position with the mouse mid zoom.

Unfortunately I cant seem to get my head around the best way of going about this.

Here is a working jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3k332/15/

Thanks in advance for any help.

**NOTE:**  I am well aware that there is some redundant code in my fiddle and that its not particularly elegant but this is merely a quick mock up to help you understand the problem.

Comment: no mouse here but one thing stands out. why zoom only one notch at that first zoom? can you make the same effect (the erroneous) with two notches?

Comment: @zladuric Yes you can... I mentioned zooming only one notch since if you scroll several you will end up zooming all the way in (to my set limit of 10) in which case the problem would not be seen.  The number of notches is not important.  As long as you change mouse position somewhere between the scale of 1-10, then the problem will be visible.